# hibernate entity is not mapped since version 4.3.2

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

With the change hibernate (hibernate-entitymanager) version 4.3.1.Final to 4.3.2.Final my HQL-Statements do not work anymore.

I made a working example with hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.1.Final. And tested with hibernate-entitymanager version higher then 4.3.1.Final and it fails. Here is my test:

pom snippet:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

persistence.xml snippet:

```
<persistence-unit name="devsample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/edokuTest"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xyz"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

entity-Class:

```
package myentity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyAdress implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6973060018308115304L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String Strasse;

    public String getStrasse() {
        return Strasse;
    }

    public void setStrasse(String strasse) {
        Strasse = strasse;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

JUNIT-Test:

```
package dao.test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RmsSimpleTest {

    public static EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("devsample")
            .createEntityManager();

    @Test
    public void testQuery() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM MyAdress");

        query.getResultList();
        int resultList = query.getMaxResults();

        long estimatedTime = java.lang.System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Time: " + String.format("%d milsec", TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(estimatedTime)));
    }
}
```

When I run the test with new hibernate-entitymanager version > 4.3.1.Final I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyAdress is not mapped [FROM MyAdress]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at dao.test.RmsSimpleTest.testQuery(RmsSimpleTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyAdress is not mapped [FROM MyAdress]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyAdress is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 32 more
```

Well when I put package-name in front of entity like this: createQuery("FROM myentity.MyAdress"); than the query is also not executed. I get not Exception, but the result ist empty:

```
1740 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter  - HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: FROM myentity.MyAdress
```

Comment: Do you have a table with name 'MyAdress' in place??

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly add your entity class to the persistence.xml? Like adding the line `<class>myentity.MyAdress</class>` as a child of the `<persistence-unit>` node?

Comment: well it worked. But I have >80 enities so I dont' want to write each entity in persistent.xml

Comment: @Pratik: yes, my table will be generated by hibernate and it has by default the same name as my entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared your entity classes in persistence.xml config file:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
```

ir supply the jar-file

```
 <jar-file>file:./target/classes</jar-file>
```

Comment: Entities will be scaned in classpath by default. I added your property and it doesn't help.

Comment: I changed the path in <jar-file>file:../target/classes</jar-file> to <jar-file>file:./target/classes</jar-file> and put in persistence.xml in <persistent-unit>. Now it works. So I will accept your answert. But someone should report this as a bug it to hibernate.